# Set and retrieve width using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem using JQuery. I am writing a function that dynamically resizes an absolute positioned 'ul' width according to the previous sibling's width (which is an 'h4'). The code is:

```
$(this).children('h4').each(function (i) {
   var beforeWidth = $(this).width(); // This reads for example 234
   $(this).next().width($(this).width()); // This should set the width
   var afterWidth = $(this).next().get(0).clientWidth; // This returns always 0
});
```

HTML is like that:

```
<div style="width: 30%;">
   <h4>title</h4>
   <ul style="position: absolute;">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I can't understand why it returns 0, so my 'ul' is always smaller than the corresponding 'h4'. I have to say that 'h4' width is set in CSS using a percentage value.

EDIT: I should have said that this happens only if that piece of code is inside a hidden div (that I use as a modal popup). Otherwise it works as expected!

Thank you guys!

Comment: This seems like a very convoluted way of doing things, there must be a better way.

Comment: Can't just use plain CSS for such things? There is no attribute 'clientWidth' on most HTML elements, it's only a property of document.body.

Comment: is this jquery in some event? where does he get `$(this)` from?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is inside a plugin, but I don't think this is important.

Comment: oh btw, they have the same width on my screen :P I gave them some colors to make it clear. http://jsfiddle.net/QPMjQ/
thats without ANY jquery

Comment: The UL is absolutely positioned because it is a sort of dropdown list!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var afterWidth = $(this).next().get(0).clientWidth;
```

To

```
var afterWidth = $(this).next().width();
```

And it should work

Comment: That is only a breakpoint to watch the computed value, and it always returns 0. I really can't understand why. Sorry, read my EDIT in the first post.

Comment: But where is it 0 then? because on that particular line its not 0 and I cant see you sending the value of it to any other place by returning. so if you try to catch the value somewhere else you will have to return it first otherwise its 0 forever

Comment: @Alessandro In fact it returns "undefined" instead of a 0, because there is no attribute 'clientWidth'…

Comment: Its a plugin, so we dont see the clientWidth but it might be there ;)

Comment: @Teun Pronk

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth

Specification: Not part of any W3C specification.

Notes: clientWidth was first introduced in the MS IE DHTML object model.

Comment: clientWidth is a Javascript property, so you have to use get(0) to return the real DOM element. But the problem is absolute positioning.